# How to check that extracted FBX indices are correct?

Tags: import, fbx, assimp

I am trying to import FBX file using FBX SDK. Reference was "ImportScene" sample of FBX. I've extracted vertices (control point in FBX) and indices. I wanted to check whether the extracted values are correct by comparing the values using other library on same FBX file. The other library is ASSIMP. However, the extracted values of each library are different and I have no idea the values of which library is correct. I've tried to check which values are correct using other tools such as Blender and Unity. However, I couldn't find way to see the table of vertex indices. So my question is

**Q. How to check that extracted FBX indices are correct?**

Below are extracted values from FBX SDK and ASSIMP.

|  | FBX SDK | ASSIMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vertices | [image: FBX_Vertex] | [image] |
| Indices | [image] | [image] |
| Triangulate | [image] | [image] |

**[Assumption]**

My assumption is
FBX vertices are correct while ASSIMP vertices z values are inverted (to negative).
FBX indices are correct while ASSIMP indices are wrong.

The reason for assumption is
Vertex count is 2409, face count is 4602 in Blender.
FBX SDK gives 4602 faces and all GetPolygonSize gives 3, which means 13806 (= 4602 * 3) vertices (overlapping).
However, ASSIMP gives 10482 vertices and some vertices have exact same x, y, z values. It seems ASSIMP is trying to give overlapping vertices. 10482 vertices seem weird anyway.

But assumption is assumption. I'd want to check the extracted values by model viewer that can show tables of imported mesh's vertices and indices. However, I could not find so far.

If anyone helps, it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Asset-Importer-Lib will reorganize all your inidces. We are doing this for geometry-optimization. So just comparing the indices directly will not work for your kind of use-case.